# npm i won't work thanks to some dependency building error

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-sass

I'm using Node 12 since it's an old project. I already tried Node 18. An `npm update` didn't work either. NPM version can be fetched from log and I don't know what you could need more.

EDIT:
I also tried to delete the node_modules directory.
Fixed the link to logfile.

EDIT2:
I resolved it. I needed one specific npm and node version not a single minor version above or below...

Here's the log: https://pastebin.com/XqyeMYqM

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "fontawesome": "npm config set \"@fortawesome:registry\" https://npm.fontawesome.com/ && npm config set \"//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken\" token",
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
        "axios": "^0.17",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
        "babel-plugin-transform-object-assign": "^6.22.0",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.1.0",
        "less": "^2.7.3",
        "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.10",
        "sass-resources-loader": "^1.3.3",
        "uglify-es": "^3.3.10",
        "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.6",
        "vue": "^2.5.16",
        "vue-particles": "^1.0.9",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.0.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.8",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.10.1",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands": "^5.0.13",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular": "^5.0.13",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-light": "^5.0.13",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro-regular": "^5.0.13",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.21",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.10.1",
        "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.6",
        "babel-plugin-transform-remove-strict-mode": "0.0.2",
        "cypress": "^3.1.0",
        "es6-promise": "^4.2.4",
        "flickity-fullscreen": "^1.1.0",
        "fs": "0.0.1-security",
        "global-res": "file:../../resources/assets",
        "module": "^1.2.5",
        "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
        "spectrumNPM": "git+https://credential@gitlab.tkw-partner.de/spectrum-unlimited/spectrumNPM.git",
        "vue-agile": "^0.3.7",
        "vue-axios": "^2.1.1",
        "vue-flickity": "^1.1.2",
        "vue-gtm": "^1.0.2",
        "vue-infinite-loading": "^2.3.1",
        "vue-loader": "^13.7.2",
        "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
        "vue-spinner": "^1.0.3",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.16",
        "vue-toasted": "^1.1.24",
        "vue-transmit": "^8.1.4",
        "vuex": "^3.0.1",
        "vuex-persistedstate": "^2.5.4",
        "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^3.3.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: try this one "npm update --force"

Comment: it's no good idea since the project is really old and depends on old stuff which would throw one error after another if I just update the whole dependency tree

Comment: normal thing when encounter old nodejs project, i usually try all the major node version and install the project until it doesnt get error https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases

Answer (score 0):

The link to your logs does not seem to be working for me, so I can't see the actual error you're getting. So I can just share a few pointers on how I usually approach any problems when `npm i` throws errors.

First of all, if you have an old `package-lock.json` or old `node_modules`, delete them (potentially backing them up first) and see if that already helps get `npm i` unstuck.

If that does not help, create a new project and copy your dependencies over one by one. See which one actually breaks. That probably won't fix your issue outright, but helps narrow down what the actual problem is. If you find just one package causing trouble like that, see if you can remove it or use a different plugin for the same job.

If you can share your logs somewhere else so others can access them, you might get more concrete help.

Comment: sry don't know how that could happen but i fixed the link now: https://pastebin.com/XqyeMYqM